# facebook send data users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

A and B are friends and A have many friends and B have many friends. and one application exists. How can A send data to the wall of B,provided that wall/newsfeed of A cant have that data and only B knows that data.

By using PHP SDK, or JS SDK

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using graph API
You will have to first retrieve the access_token of that application for A ( see FB documentation )
Then using that access_token you can post on B's wall as A
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Hi B.. whazzup ? ' \
     https://graph.facebook.com//feed

but somehow the text only appears in B's wall only ..

Facebook Documentation for same
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of short screencasts for developers on getting started with the Facebook OpenGraph API - they are [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8D1E905D80087F6F&feature=plcp).